# Why does C# Entity Framework Continue to Revert to the Initial Migration Point

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I can't seem to figure out why EF constantly reverts all the way back to the first migration point. It drops most of my tables and of course all data is reverted.

I have a good handle on how the migrations are tracked and updated, but it seems like the following configuration options are completely ignored in my DBMigration config..

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ProjectName.DAL.myDbcontext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ProjectName.DAL.myDbcontext)
    {
    }
}
```

I have been deploying this to our server, and there are certainly times where the binaries on the server do not match our local development area. Am I missing something here?

Why do AutomaticMigrationsEnabled/AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed not stop EF from completely wiping out our database? I had to upgrade SQL license so I could do automated backups every 30 minutes for constant fear of losing data.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What DbInitializer do you use? Maybe it just doesn't use your migrations at all?

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I believe you are correct.. First EF project and I was focusing too much on the migration aspect. **DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges** - I have changed this to **CreateDatabaseIfNotExists** .. Should be good, yes? 

Thanks for your answer @SergeyLitvinov

Answer (score 1):

If you want EF to use your migration, then you need to choice `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` class and specify it like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ProjectName.DAL.myDbcontext, Configuration>());
```

And then EF will use your actual migrations and `Configuration` settings that you specified.
You can also specify database initializer in web.config, if you don't like to do it in the code.

`CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` wont use your migration. It will just verify that database exists, and if not, then it will create it based on your DbContext. The only initializer that uses migrations and Configuration file is `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`

If you don't want to use migrations and all, then yes, you can specify `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` or even `NullDatabaseInitializer` that won't do anything.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you Sergey..  Since your original comment I have been reading up on the initializers also - thank you for pointing us in the right direction. 

Which of the basic initalizer classes should the actual Initalizer class inherit from in that case? (I changed to Createifnotexists etc) Or will that be ignored per the explicit "SetInitializer" call in the dbContext class?

Comment: np :) `SetInitializer` says explicitly what initializer should be used, so you can use any of existing, or even make own if you need some custom behavior.   So if you have custom initializer that inherits CreateIfNotExists but you don't set it in `SetInitializer` call, then it will be ignored.